# Undefined offset: 1 in cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Hello I'd been exploring of using framework cakephp in implementing sites. In my current PHP script this error comes up: Undefined offset: 1 and its already giving me a headache. Can you guys help me out what I am doing wrong.

My code is here:

```
function file_upload($file_array, $id){
    if(count($file_array))
    {
        $location = "files/library-files/";

        foreach ($file_array as $file) {
            $ext = explode(".", $file['name']);
            $new_name = md5(uniqid());
            $target_path = $location . $new_name .".".$ext[1];
            if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path))
            {
                $this->LibraryFiles->create();
                $this->LibraryFiles->set('id', $new_name);
                $this->LibraryFiles->set('library_id', $id);
                $this->LibraryFiles->set('name', $file['name']);
                $this->LibraryFiles->set('ext', $ext[1]);
                $this->LibraryFiles->set('type', $file['type']);
                $this->LibraryFiles->set('size', $file['size']);
                if($this->LibraryFiles->save())
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a file in your file array without a dot inside, or a pointer to the upper directory?

Comment: it is this line $target_path = $location . $new_name .".".$ext[1]; that was giving me errors. with hours of research I replaced it with      
if (isset($target_path)) $target_path = $location . $new_name .".".$ext[1]; else $target_path = ''; and now no more errors :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just replaced this $target_path = $location . $new_name .".".$ext[1];

with

```
if (isset($target_path)) 
$target_path = $location . $new_name .".".$ext[1]; 
else 
$target_path = '';
```

and now I am happy :D

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following check:

```
if(isset($ext[1]))
{
    $target_path = $location . $new_name .".".$ext[1];
}
else if($file['name'] !== '.' && $file['name'] !== '..')
{
    $target_path = $location . $new_name;
}
else
{
    continue;
}
```